# How can I decode the HTML &amp; to & without allowing a <script> block to be run in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently using the following code in PHP.

```
echo html_entity_decode($productName);
```

However, if this value is something like `<script>alert("Alert!")</script>`, this script will ultimately be executed as well. I want to decode the HTML without allowing scripts to be run.

Comment: What about `stript_tags(html_entity_decode($productName))`?

Comment: html purifier, strip out anything script-related.

Comment: if you literally just wanted ampersand like the title implies you could just replace all `&amp;` with `&` using `str_replace`

Comment: If you are echoing, it's completely wrong to decode your code unless it really represent markup that will be injected in the page. This will make your HTML invalid.